# next js multi-domain middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

im getting this error in the below code
error - Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
also i want to run redirectMiddleware for one time for each user who will access this website
can someone suggest some better way to achieve this

```
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next'
import redirectMiddleware from '../lib/middleware.js'


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return( 

        <Component {...pageProps} />
    )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const { ctx } = appContext;
  if (!ctx.req._middlewareExecuted) {
    try {
      // Use the middleware
      await redirectMiddleware(ctx.req, ctx.res);

      // Set a flag on the request object to indicate that the middleware has been executed
      ctx.req._middlewareExecuted = true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in getInitialProps:', error);
      // Handle the error as needed
    }
  }
  return {};
};

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp)
```

```
import axios from 'axios';

const redirectMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      // Fetch the user's IP address
      const response = await axios.get('https://ipinfo.io/json');
      const { country } = response.data;

      // Perform the redirection based on the country
      if (country === 'QA') {
        res.writeHead(307, { Location: 'qatardomain' });
        res.end();
      } else if (country === 'US') {
        res.writeHead(307, { Location: 'usadomain' });
        res.end();
      } else if (country === 'CA') {
        res.writeHead(307, { Location: 'canadadomain' });
        res.end();
      } else {
        // Default redirection
        res.writeHead(307, { Location: 'default domain' });
        res.end();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching user information:', error);
      next(); // Proceed to the next middleware or route
    }
};

export default redirectMiddleware;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out

```js
import axios from 'axios';

let redirectExecuted = false;

const redirectMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (redirectExecuted) {
      next();
      return;
    }
    const response = await axios.get('https://ipinfo.io/json');
    const { country } = response.data;

    let redirectLocation = '';

    if (country === 'QA') {
      redirectLocation = 'qatardomain';
    } else if (country === 'US') {
      redirectLocation = 'usadomain';
    } else if (country === 'CA') {
      redirectLocation = 'canadadomain';
    } else {
      // Default redirection
      redirectLocation = 'default domain';
    }

    redirectExecuted = true;
    res.writeHead(307, { Location: redirectLocation });
    res.end();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching user information:', error);
    next();
  }
};

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    redirectMiddleware();
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: not worked 
any other way i can implement my logic in next js

Comment: Do you prefer it the same way you asked question @Teejaay?